# single quotes for string keys in javascript object

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, object

In nodejs I was creating a list of objects with each object supposed to have a string key and a number as value.  I am able to create this without issues but while trying to log this with console.log() . I could see some keys did not have a single quotes surrounding the key while some did.

eg

```
[
    { '2d22f294': 0 },    
    { b6d108da: 0 },
    { b17562ff: 0 },
    { '0e4a0beb': 0 }
  ]
```

Could anyone explain what does it mean to have a single quotes surrounding the key , I was of the assumption this meant the key was a string but even the ones without single quotes around the keys are strings and act like strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an object like this

```
let object = {
    name: 'Jim',
    25: 'Age'
}
```

You can access the properties in the following way:

- for the `name`key ... `object.name` or `object['name']`.
- for the key `25` ... `object[25]` or `object['25']`

This is because properties cannot start with a number in js. Therefore you have to access them with brackets.

Answer (score 4):

If it's starts with a number, then printing must show you valid javascript and quotes tell you that the key is a string (not a number).